# adobe air application how to run in background

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I need to make my air app to disappear when I press a button or to run in background for about 5 seconds and close it after that.
How can I do this? thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force close your AIR app by simply calling

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit()
```

That doesn't work in AIR. For that you will have to write a simple ANE and call android code to exit application. We also forced closed our AIR android app by ANE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to control if your app is visible, the android OS controls that.

You can detect if your app is about to be suspended by listening for the `Event.DEACTIVATE` from the `NativeApplication.nativeApplication` object.

You can close your app with `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit()`, however it wont be a "background" process.

Comment: thank you for response. When I'm trying to exit with NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit() and I also have Event.DEACTIVATE, that means the application will be closed and the deactivate handler will continue until the handler function will be finised?

Comment: Yes, however `Event.DEACTIVATE` is vulnerable to force close commands (just as all processes are). In normal situations any code in the listener of that event will execute.